# How to use jquery auto-complete in rails application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I am using rails 4. I have tried to use auto-complete in my application. But when installing autocomplete , it throws error like could not find generator autocomplete:install.

Please guide me how to use autocomplete in my application.

In View

```
<%= simple_form_for @vehicle_driver,remote: true, html: {class: 'form-inline form-horizontal vehicle_driver' }, :validate => true do |f| %>
<div class="control-group string optional vehicle_driver_vehicle_code">
    <label class="string optional control-label" for="vehicle_code">Vehicle</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <%= f.select :vehicle_id, vehicle_assign_driver, {},{}  %>
     <%= link_to new_vehicle_path do %>
       <span class='icon-plus-sign'></span><br>
    <% end %>

  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="control-group string optional vehicle_driver_driver_name">
    <label class="string optional control-label" for="driver_name">Driver</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <%= f.select :driver_id,  driver_list, {},{}    %>
     <%= link_to new_driver_path do %>
      <span class='icon-plus-sign'></span><br>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
   <div style="padding-left:15em">
 <%= f.button  :submit, {value:'Assign', class: 'btn btn-primary'} %>
 <span id="updated1" class="inline icon-ok hidden" style="display: none;">Assigned Successfully</span>
</div>
<% end %>
```

In Application controller

```
def driver_list
        Driver.where(:driver_allotted => false).map{|i|[i.first_name.capitalize, i.id]}
    end
```

I am using f.select for displaying driver list in drop down. Instead of that it will show on auto-complete.

How to use auto-complete in simple form . Please Share your ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple:

In view you need a text_field.

In your js file:

```
$( "#driver_id" ).autocomplete({ source: "/controller_name?filter_key=attr_name", minLength: 0 });
```

In your controller you will get `params[:term]` with the text_field value:

```
if params[:term]
  @drivers = Driver.where(filter_key.to_sym => params[:term]).map(&filter_key.to_sym)
end
```

Please DO NOT put your drivers code in application_controller, put it in driver_controller.