# Rails set variable equal to text field in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I want to create a text field box in a view that as a user starts typing/deleting text from the box the view is auto-populated with information from the database.

To start with, I need to know how to create a text box in my view that will take whatever input it is given and assign it to a variable that my controller action can use.

Then, how can I make that happen as a user is typing instead of the user having to submit the text?

Something like this:

## persons/index.html.erb

```
`text-form-input-value = @person_name`
<%= @names %>
```

## persons_controller.rb

```
def index
    @names = Person.where(:name => @person_name)
end
```

Comment: This is about Javascript autocomplete. Not a simple step job if you don't know it's related to Javascript yet. You can search around Google to find basic ideas.

Comment: Gotcha - That's enough to get me started, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Solr/Sunspot does faceted searches, that will give you the results to query, then an ajax query to fetch it to populate you view, that's where I would start

Comment: check out this gem. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19271753/2503775